# Capturar etiquetas html a través de un input en jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

¿Cómo puedo leer las etiquetas HTML que paso por un input en el JSP?

Cuando escribo `<b>prueba</b>` en el input, en el get del JSP solo recoge "prueba", sin las etiquetas.

¿Cómo podría leer esas etiquetas?

Comment: ¿Qué servidor de aplicaciones estás usando? ¿Estás enviando la información al servidor vía *submit*?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo por AJAX si te está escapando los caracteres (cuestión de seguridad, para evitar ataques `XSS`).

```js
// para evitar escribir mucho ;)
window.$ = function(selector) { return document.querySelector(selector); }
window.$$ = function(selector) { return document.querySelectorAll(selector); }

$('#tu-form').onsubmit = (e) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', $('#tu-form').getAttribute('action'), true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 &&  xhr.status === 200) {
            // petición exitosa, hacer algo si se desea
        }
    };
    // cambiar a POST si quieres crear un JSON
    const data = serialize('#tu-form', 'GET');
    console.log(data);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    e.preventDefault();
}

/**
 * Serializa un formulario de acuerdo a GET o POST
 */
function serialize(e, method) {
    const form = (typeof e == 'HTMLFormElement') ? e : $(e);
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    if(method.toUpperCase() === 'GET') {
        let data = '';
        [].forEach.call(inputs, (input) => {
            data += `${input.getAttribute("name")}=${input.value}&`;
        });
        return data.replace(/&(?!.*?&)/, '');
    }
    if(method.toUpperCase() === 'POST') {
        let data = {};
        [].forEach.call(inputs, (input) => {
            data[input.getAttribute('name')] = input.value;
        });
        return data;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="/TuServlet" id="tu-form">
  <input type="text" name="a" />
  <input type="text" name="b" />
  <input type="text" name="c" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias !! Aun que no puedo hacerlo con AJAX Mitsu, ese es el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué inconveniente tendrías en hacerlo, @Cucumberita?

Comment: @Cucumberita parece como si tuvieses un filtro en tu aplicación que remueve esos caracteres de html, ¿puedes confirmar algo así? (el XSS se evita de lado del servidor al mostrar los datos, no de lado del cliente al enviar el request, el navegador no quita esa info a menos que tengas un agente o una especie de parser que lo quite)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza mi pensamiento era que Java escapaba los tags en las peticiones por seguridad. ¿No es así?

Comment: No, no lo hace por defecto, ese tipo de cosas debes manejarlas manualmente o utilizar algún framework que lo escape por ti.